# Counting customers from different countries, country table will not join to customer table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to count the amount of customers from each country but the statement does not seem to be working. It keeps saying invalid identifier.

The customers are in the customer_details table and then the country name is determined by the country_id in another table.

I cannot seem to get this statement to work.

```
SELECT country.country, count(*) AS customer_count
FROM customer_details
INNER JOIN country
ON customer_details.country_id = country.country_id
GROUP by country.country
ORDER by country.country;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `From country join country`... Did you mean `join customer_details`?

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo...

Comment: Sorry, yes customer_details. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the following query (presuming there is a column named customer_id) :

```
SELECT country.country, count(customer_details.customer_id) AS customer_count
FROM country
INNER JOIN customer_details
ON customer_details.country_id = country.country_id
GROUP by country.country
ORDER by country.country;
```

**EDIT :** You mention you have a column named customer_name, address etc. You can use these any of these columns as well since the `join` clause will only fetch the results where country is mentioned and the `group by` clause will ensure that the results will be grouped by the country name.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I do not have a customer_id but instead composite key of name, address. I feel this is bad practice but for the coursework I am doing that is the way to do it.

Your code works (thank you!) although I can only use either name or address as the identifier rather than both which is not going to ensure that each record is unique. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @frick3r Then it that case you can either use the name field or the address field.